# 4 errores en un ejemplo (java)

Tags: java

```
class Demo { 
  public static void main(String args[]){
    byte x;
    int a=270;
    double b =128.128;

    System.out.println("int converted to byte");
    x=(byte) a;
    System.out.println("a and x "+ a +" "+x);
    System.out.println("double converted to int");
    a=(int) b;
    System.out.println("b and a "+ b +" "+a);
    System.out.println("\n double converted to byte");
    x = b;
    System.out.println("b and x "+b +" "+x);
  } 
}
```

Esto muestra 4 errores de los cuales resolví 3, el último me dice que es de tipos incompatibles para double a byte... como he empezado recién y los ejemplos están en inglés, entiendo poco, si alguien pudiera decirme como arreglar ese error se lo agradecería.

Comment: Alguien podría editar el titulo con el error que lanza su código, o algo menos ambiguo?

Answer (score 2):

El error principal es en la linea señalada, son tipos incompatibles, no puedes realizar una conversión de [double a byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) directamente, tiene que realizar un [casting](http://www.discoduroderoer.es/casting-en-java/):

```
byte x;
int a=270;
double b =128.128;
System.out.println("int converted to byte");
x=(byte) a;
System.out.println("a and x "+ a +" "+x);
System.out.println("double converted to int");
a=(int) b;
System.out.println("b and a "+ b +" "+a);
System.out.println("\n double converted to byte");
// x= b;  //Error tipos incompatibles!.
x= (byte)b;
System.out.println("b and x "+b +" "+x);
```

Tienes que realizar in casting a tipo byte.

Para tener una salida correcta:

```
int converted to byte
a and x 270 14
double converted to int
b and a 128.128 128

 double converted to byte
b and x 128.128 -128
```

---

Con respecto al Casting agrego esta información de [ADRformacion](http://www.adrformacion.com/curso/java/leccion2/tipos_variables.htm)

**[Casting o transformaciones de tipo](http://www.adrformacion.com/curso/java/leccion2/tipos_variables.htm)**

El casting es un procedimiento para transformar una variable primitiva de un tipo a otro, o transformar un objeto de una clase a otra clase siempre y cuando haya una relación de herencia entre ambas (este último casting es el más importante y se verá más adelante).

Dentro del casting de variables primitivas se distinguen dos clases:

Implícito: no se necesita escribir código para que se lleve a cabo. Ocurre cuando se realiza una conversión ancha (widening casting), es decir, cuando se coloca un valor pequeño en un contenedor grande.
Ejemplo 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo 2: similar al anterior.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explícito: sí es necesario escribir código. Ocurre cuando se realiza una conversión estrecha (narrowing casting), es decir, cuando se coloca un valor grande en un contenedor pequeño. Son susceptibles de pérdida de datos.
Ejemplo 1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> NOTA: si se sustituyera la primera línea int num1=100 por int
>   num1=1000000, el código compilaría bien, pero habría pérdida de datos,
>   pues el 1000000 se sale del rango de short [-32768, 32767]. Al mostrar
>   por consola el valor se obtendría un resultado incongruente.

Ejemplo 2:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo 3: continuación del Ejemplo 2 del casting implícito

Para que la línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

compile debe hacerse un casting explícito a long

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque, en la línea anterior, 10000000000 es considerado int, mientras que en las de arriba, double.

Comment: al cambiar el x=b; a x=(byte) b; compilo... lo de casting a que se refiere?, es que son terminos nuevos y este era recien un ejemplo

Comment: =0!, ok. Agregue un link donde describe que es casting en idioma espanol: http://www.discoduroderoer.es/casting-en-java/ , básicamente se refiere a convertir un objeto de un tipo a otro.

Answer (score 1):

Tu variable `x` es de tipo `Byte` y `b` es `Double` por eso no podrás asignar ¿ Por qué ? `int` de **32 bits**.  y `byte` **8 bits** , conviértela (Hazle el Casting) a `Byte`

```
x= (byte) b;
```

> Casting : Es un procedimiento para transformar una variable primitiva
>   de un tipo a otro, o transformar un objeto de una clase a otra clase
>   siempre y cuando haya una relación de herencia entre ambas